# How to print or get the cell value from HTML TABLE(User Input) in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to grab the cell values from an HTML table so that I can display them into a table.

How do I grab the cell's value so that I can pass it to the table cells My JavaScript code below show a page not found?

Code:

```js
function getValues() {

  let item = itemName;

  if (item == null) 

    alert("Please you need to fill all fields  to continue");

    else

      alert("success")

  

  //Data collection

  var itemName = document.getElementsByName("itemName")[0].value;

  var itemQty = document.getElementsByName("itemQty")[0].value;

  var itemPrice = document.getElementsByName("itemPrice")[0].value;

  var itemAmt = itemPrice * itemQty;


  var itemDate = document.getElementsByName("itemDate")[0].value;

  var total = "Your total amount of items bought is " + " " + "#" + itemAmt;

  //data display

  document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML = total;

  document.getElementById("itemName").innerHTML = (itemName);

  document.getElementById("itemQty").innerHTML = (itemQty);

  document.getElementById("itemPrice").innerHTML = (itemPrice);

  document.getElementById("itemAmt").innerHTML = (itemAmt);

  document.getElementById("itemDate").innerHTML = (itemDate);

  //conditional statement for empty field

  // if ( itemAmt === true){

  alert(total)

  //  }else{

  // alert("Please you need to fill all fields  to continue")

  //}  

}
```

```css
  body {
  background: #fff;
}

.tag {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  justify-space: in-between;
}

#item {
  width: 19.35%;
  height: auto;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  width: 19.35%;
  height: auto;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  .frame {
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    background: grey;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    color: #231ccb;
  }
```

```html
<div class="frame">

  <p><label> Item:<input type="text" name="itemName" placeholder="item" required> </label></p>

  <br>

  <p><label> Quantity:<input type="text" name="itemQty" required> </label></p>

  <br>

  <p><label> Price :<input type="number" name="itemPrice" required> </label></p>

  <!--<br>
   
        <p><label> Amount: <input type="number" name="itemAmt" placeholder="#" required> </label></p>-->

  <br>

  <p><label> Date :<input type="Date" name="itemDate" required> </label></p>

</div>

<br>

<button onclick="getValues()"> Add Item </button>

</form>

<!--Table Header-->

<div class="tag">

  <div id="item">Item Name</div>

  <div id="item">Quantity</div>

  <div id="item">Price</div>

  <div id="item">Amount</div>

  <div id="item">Date</div>

  <!--Display item variable-->

  <div class="item">

    <p id="itemName"></p>

  </div>

  <div class="item">

    <p id="itemQty"> </p>

  </div>

  <div class="item">

    <p id="itemPrice"></p>

  </div>

  <div class="item">

    <p id="itemAmt"> </p>

  </div>

  <div class="item">

    <p id="itemDate"></p>

  </div>

  <br>

  <br>

  <br>

  <p id="tag"> Hello world</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Not A Bot.. the correction you provided is very useful. The values can transfer to the table but I still get alert 'Please you need to fill all fields  to continue' even when the table is filled. I expect to get the alert when the the user did not fill the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **exclamation mark** (`!`) symbol, called a **bang**, which is the logical `NOT` operator.

Below is the demo code, you can take reference from here.

`!` will help us to find if any **input** is **empty** or **null** or **undefined**.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#add-items");

btn.addEventListener("click", addItems);

function addItems() {
  let itemName = document.querySelector("#item-name").value;
  
  let itemQnt = document.querySelector("#item-quantity").value;
  
  if(!itemName) alert("Please provide item name.");
  else if(!itemQnt) alert("Please provide item quantity.");
  else alert("Success");
}
```

```html
<label for="item-name"> Item Name: 
  <input type="text" placeholder="Item Name" id="item-name" />
</label>

<br><br>

<label for="item-quantity"> Item Quantity: 
  <input type="number" placeholder="Item Quantity" id="item-quantity" />
</label>

<br><br>
<button type="button" id="add-items">Add Item</button>
```

Now, coming to your code, a few of these needs to be changed in your code.

1. You are checking for `itemName` for null, even before its value is been ready by your code.
   Thus, every time even with correct data, your **if** condition will be evaluated, the corresponding `alert` will be triggered.
2. You need to put everything which is related to the calculation of total price and the display code, inside your **else** condition after the **if** condition fails to evaluate to `true`.

```js
function getValues() {

  var itemName = document.getElementsByName("itemName")[0].value;

  var itemQty = document.getElementsByName("itemQty")[0].value;

  var itemPrice = document.getElementsByName("itemPrice")[0].value;

  var itemDate = document.getElementsByName("itemDate")[0].value;

  if (!itemName || !itemQty || !itemPrice || !itemDate) {
    alert("Please you need to fill all fields  to continue");
  } else {
    alert("success")

    var itemAmt = itemPrice * itemQty;

    var total = "Your total amount of items bought is " + " " + "#" + itemAmt;

    //data display

    document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML = total;

    document.getElementById("itemName").innerHTML = (itemName);

    document.getElementById("itemQty").innerHTML = (itemQty);

    document.getElementById("itemPrice").innerHTML = (itemPrice);

    document.getElementById("itemAmt").innerHTML = (itemAmt);

    document.getElementById("itemDate").innerHTML = (itemDate);


    alert(total)


  }
}
```

```css
  }
body {
  background: #fff;
}
.tag {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  justify-space: in-between;
}
#item {
  width: 19.35%;
  height: auto;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.item {
  width: 19.35%;
  height: auto;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  .frame {
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    background: grey;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    color: #231ccb;
  }
```

```html
<div class="frame">

  <p><label> Item:<input type="text" name="itemName" placeholder="item" required> </label></p>

  <br>

  <p><label> Quantity:<input type="text" name="itemQty" required> </label></p>

  <br>

  <p><label> Price :<input type="number" name="itemPrice" required> </label></p>


  <br>

  <p><label> Date :<input type="Date" name="itemDate" required> </label></p>

</div>

<br>

<button onclick="getValues()"> Add Item </button>

</form>

<!--Table Header-->

<div class="tag">

  <div id="item">Item Name</div>

  <div id="item">Quantity</div>

  <div id="item">Price</div>

  <div id="item">Amount</div>

  <div id="item">Date</div>

  <!--Display item variable-->

  <div class="item">

    <p id="itemName"></p>

  </div>

  <div class="item">

    <p id="itemQty"> </p>

  </div>

  <div class="item">

    <p id="itemPrice"></p>

  </div>

  <div class="item">

    <p id="itemAmt"> </p>

  </div>

  <div class="item">

    <p id="itemDate"></p>

  </div>

  <br>

  <br>

  <br>

  <p id="tag"> Hello world</p>

</div>
```